# Is "Mother Mary" from The Beatles' Let It Be a reference to marijuana?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, the-beatles

I'm wondering if the lyrics of the The Beatles song Let It Be are about drugs and marijuana. Does anyone here know?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not, as per this [quote](https://mattandjojang.wordpress.com/2009/05/03/the-story-behind-paul-mccartneys-song-let-it-be/) from Paul McCartney himself, the song is about his mother coming to him in a dream.

The quote appears in *[Many Years From Now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_McCartney:_Many_Years_from_Now?oldformat=true)*, the official biography of Paul McCartney from 1997 (as mentioned by jcbermu in the comments below).

Comment: The quote appears in [Many years from now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_McCartney:_Many_Years_from_Now?oldformat=true) the official biography of Paul McCartney from 1997.

Comment: Thanks jcbermu, that settles it then, with a good reliable source.